# Unable to deploy metadata type

Tags: metadata, deployment-api, retrieve

I am working on a project where I need to deploy the zip file back to the production org which I got after the retrieve() call.

Things that I tried:-

1. Firstly, I tried to deploy the complete zip file using the deploy() metadata call. but since in production, we must explicitly need to make rollback on the error as true. so, if any one of the file's deployment gets failed then complete deployment's success became false
   [image]

> because of these 65 failed components, my whole deployment failed(even I tried to fix why these 65 components are failing manually, but that doesn't seem to be a permanent solution as for different org different error is coming for same metadata types)

2. Secondly, What I tried is to retrieve a single metadata component at a time and then deploy that single retrieved back. Here, I have tried multiple datatypes {Appex class, Email template}
   All the files which are present inside the package.xml are successfully deployed (**componentSuccesses(all files)**) but the deployment success is still **false**. for both the metadata types same error message is coming.
   [image]
   ( for email deploy)

Any lead, how can I achieve this deployment feature.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the metadata types that you are facing issues with are, as the amount of errors is not a helpful benchmark to go by.

Comment: General pointers though:
1. There is the option "Rollback on Error" which you can se to false if you want partial deployments to succeed. That would take care of the problems you had where 65 metadata components did not work
2. Did you retrieve the code from a managed package? It has a namespace and all... However in this case, you need to specify a Test Class to run that does something to Trigger the `faxTrigger`, because a Trigger needs to at least be called once in tests to be deployed.

Not jotting this down as an answer due to the first question being unclear.